# How to build hybrid model of RF(Random Forest) and PSO(Particle Swarm Optimizer) to find optimal discount of products?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, mathematical-optimization, particle-swarm

I need to find optimal discount for each product (in e.g. A, B, C) so that I can maximize total sales. I have existing Random Forest models for each product that map discount and season to sales.  How do I combine these models and feed them to an optimiser to find the optimum discount per product?

Reason for model selection:

1. RF: it's able to give better(w.r.t linear models) relation between predictors and response(sales_uplift_norm).
2. PSO: suggested in many white papers(available at researchgate/IEEE), also availability of the package in python [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyswarm/) and [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyswarm/).

**Input data**: [sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/gl1u4uluqtq4avyvbdqd0/so_data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=exotknjldutoi9zh7dbv5p8k6) used to build model at product level. Glance of the data as below:
[image]

Idea/Steps followed by me:

1. Build RF model per products

```
    # pre-processed data
    products_pre_processed_data = {key:pre_process_data(df, key) for key, df in df_basepack_dict.items()}
    # rf models
    products_rf_model = {key:rf_fit(df) for key, df in products_pre_processed_data .items()}
```

- Pass the model to optimizer

  - Objective function: maximize *sales_uplift_norm* (the response variable of RF model)
  - Constraint:

    - total spend(spends of A + B + C <= 20), spends = total_units_sold_of_products * discount_percentage * mrp_of_products
    - lower bound of products(A, B, C): [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] # discount percentage lower bounds
    - upper bound of products(A, B, C): [0.3, 0.4, 0.4] # discount percentage upper bounds

**sudo/sample code** # as I am unable to find a way to pass the product_models into optimizer.

```
from pyswarm import pso
def obj(x):
    model1 = products_rf_model.get('A')
    model2 = products_rf_model.get('B')
    model3 = products_rf_model.get('C')
    return -(model1 + model2 + model3) # -ve sign as to maximize

def con(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    x3 = x[2]
    return np.sum(units_A*x*mrp_A + units_B*x*mrp_B + units_C* x *spend_C)-20 # spend budget

lb = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
ub = [0.3, 0.4, 0.4]

xopt, fopt = pso(obj, lb, ub, f_ieqcons=con)
```

Dear SO experts, Request your guidance(*struggling to find any guidance since couple of weeks*) on how to use the **PSO optimizer(or any other optimizer if I am not following right one) with RF**.

Adding functions used for model:

```
def pre_process_data(df,product):
    data = df.copy().reset_index()
#     print(data)
    bp = product
    print("----------product: {}----------".format(bp))
    # Pre-processing steps
    print("pre process df.shape {}".format(df.shape))
        #1. Reponse var transformation
    response = data.sales_uplift_norm # already transformed

        #2. predictor numeric var transformation 
    numeric_vars = ['discount_percentage'] # may include mrp, depth
    df_numeric = data[numeric_vars]
    df_norm = df_numeric.apply(lambda x: scale(x), axis = 0) # center and scale

        #3. char fields dummification
    #select category fields
    cat_cols = data.select_dtypes('category').columns
    #select string fields
    str_to_cat_cols = data.drop(['product'], axis = 1).select_dtypes('object').astype('category').columns
    # combine all categorical fields
    all_cat_cols = [*cat_cols,*str_to_cat_cols]
#     print(all_cat_cols)

    #convert cat to dummies
    df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(data[all_cat_cols])

        #4. combine num and char df together
    df_combined = pd.concat([df_dummies.reset_index(drop=True), df_norm.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
    
    df_combined['sales_uplift_norm'] = response
    df_processed = df_combined.copy()
    print("post process df.shape {}".format(df_processed.shape))
#     print("model fields: {}".format(df_processed.columns))
    return(df_processed)


def rf_fit(df, random_state = 12):
    
    train_features = df.drop('sales_uplift_norm', axis = 1)
    train_labels = df['sales_uplift_norm']
    
    # Random Forest Regressor
    rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 500,
                               random_state = random_state,
                               bootstrap = True,
                               oob_score=True)
    # RF model
    rf_fit = rf.fit(train_features, train_labels)

    return(rf_fit)
```

**EDIT:** updated dataset to simplified version.

Comment: Can you clarify what your ultimate goal is? As the question stands, I don't see a reason for combining RF with PSO. In order to be meaningful you need some way to obtain `sales_uplift_norm` from `discount_percentage`. If this is an unknown process you can model it via RF but why would you need that for an optimization task? If you want to optimize for `discount_percentage` why can't you use the underlying process? In any case I don't see how RF would help you in that situation.

Comment: @a_guest **Ultimate goal** : I need to `find optimal discount for each products`(in e.g. A, B, C) so that I can `maximize sales` (_sum of sales of A, B, C_) such that `spend budget` (_sum of spends of products; spend of A = sales qty * discount_) is `fully utilized`. 
**Reason for using RF:** As I have historical data of these products, I am using it to find relation between `discount`, `season` and `sales`, which *RF* is able to capture better, compared to linear models.
_continued in below comments...._

Comment: **Reason for using optimizer:** Once the relation is defined in RF, I can use it as objective fun, describe the constraints and optimizer should give me optimal discount values for each products.
_Hope I am able to give clarification to your questions_.

Comment: I see. So you first fit RF with historical data to map `discount -> sales` and then you would like to find the discounts that maximize the sales (for which you plan to use PSO). If this is correct, I don't see where the problem is; it seems pretty straightforward. Can you be more precise about where you're stuck?

Comment: @a_guest yes, you are absolutely right. I am stuck on the part "how to pass the model(s) to the optimizer as an objective function." As you mentioned it as, _straightforward_ , would you **please** post the solution/working with sample data set I have shared(_even if you refer some other optimizer for the purpose_). It would be really helpful to get me going with actual large implementation.

Comment: so to clarify, the issue here is, that if it were a linear model, (with weights and biases) you would be able to pass it to an optimizer and optimize against a goal. however, since this is an ensemble based on a tree-based classifier, there is no 'model equation' with knobs to tweek by the optimiser. Am i right to assume that?

Comment: A quick addition to the above comment I made, (if you could clarify both the comments separately that would be great). IIUC, you are trying to build a relationship between discount and sales with the first model (are you doing this for each product separately?) and next you are taking that model and trying to find the minimum discount which maximizes the sales, is that correct?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Regarding _#comment1_, your assumption is absolutely right about the linear model and as well as the problem I am facing with  _tree-based regressor_.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Regarding _comment2_, **1.** yes I am trying to build model separately for each products as each product may have it's unique relationship. 
**2.**  yes that's correct as well. I am trying the same as the spend budget is defined for all product combined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can find a complete solution below !

The fundamental differences with your approach are the following :

1. Since the Random Forest model takes as input the `season` feature, optimal discounts must be computed for every season.
2. Inspecting the documentation of [pyswarm](https://pythonhosted.org/pyswarm/), the `con` function yields an output that must comply with `con(x) >= 0.0`. The correct constraint is therefore `20 - sum(...)` and not the other way around. In addition, the `units` and `mrp` variable were not given ; I just assumed a value of 1, you might want to change those values.

Additional modifications to your original code include :

1. Preprocessing and pipeline wrappers of `sklearn` in order to simplify the preprocessing steps.
2. Optimal parameters are stored in an output `.xlsx` file.
3. The `maxiter` parameter of the PSO has been set to `5` to speed-up debugging, you might want to set its value to another one (default = `100`).

The code is therefore :

```py
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor 
from sklearn.base import clone

# ====================== RF TRAINING ======================
# Preprocessing
def build_sample(season, discount_percentage):
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'season': [season],
        'discount_percentage': [discount_percentage]
    })

columns_to_encode = ["season"]
columns_to_scale = ["discount_percentage"]
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
scaler = StandardScaler()
preproc = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("encoder", Pipeline([("OneHotEncoder", encoder)]), columns_to_encode),
        ("scaler", Pipeline([("StandardScaler", scaler)]), columns_to_scale)
    ]
)

# Model
myRFClassifier = RandomForestRegressor(
    n_estimators = 500,
    random_state = 12,
    bootstrap = True,
    oob_score = True)

pipeline_list = [
    ('preproc', preproc),
    ('clf', myRFClassifier)
]

pipe = Pipeline(pipeline_list)

# Dataset
df_tot = pd.read_excel("so_data.xlsx")
df_dict = {
    product: df_tot[df_tot['product'] == product].drop(columns=['product']) for product in pd.unique(df_tot['product'])
}

# Fit
print("Training ...")
pipe_dict = {
    product: clone(pipe) for product in df_dict.keys()
}

for product, df in df_dict.items():
    X = df.drop(columns=["sales_uplift_norm"])
    y = df["sales_uplift_norm"]
    pipe_dict[product].fit(X,y)

# ====================== OPTIMIZATION ====================== 
from pyswarm import pso
# Parameter of PSO
maxiter = 5

n_product = len(pipe_dict.keys())

# Constraints
budget = 20
units  = [1, 1, 1]
mrp    = [1, 1, 1]

lb = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
ub = [0.3, 0.4, 0.4]

# Must always remain >= 0
def con(x):
    s = 0
    for i in range(n_product):
        s += units[i] * mrp[i] * x[i]

    return budget - s

print("Optimization ...")

# Save optimal discounts for every product and every season
df_opti = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df_tot.columns)
for season in pd.unique(df_tot['season']):

    # Objective function to minimize
    def obj(x):
        s = 0
        for i, product in enumerate(pipe_dict.keys()):
            s += pipe_dict[product].predict(build_sample(season, x[i]))
        
        return -s

    # PSO
    xopt, fopt = pso(obj, lb, ub, f_ieqcons=con, maxiter=maxiter)
    print("Season: {}\t xopt: {}".format(season, xopt))

    # Store result
    df_opti = pd.concat([
        df_opti,
        pd.DataFrame({
            'product': list(pipe_dict.keys()),
            'season': [season] * n_product,
            'discount_percentage': xopt,
            'sales_uplift_norm': [
                pipe_dict[product].predict(build_sample(season, xopt[i]))[0] for i, product in enumerate(pipe_dict.keys())
            ]
        })
    ])

# Save result
df_opti = df_opti.reset_index().drop(columns=['index'])
df_opti.to_excel("so_result.xlsx")
print("Summary")
print(df_opti)
```

It gives :

```
Training ...
Optimization ...
Stopping search: maximum iterations reached --> 5
Season: summer   xopt: [0.1941521  0.11233673 0.36548761]
Stopping search: maximum iterations reached --> 5
Season: winter   xopt: [0.18670604 0.37829516 0.21857777]
Stopping search: maximum iterations reached --> 5
Season: monsoon  xopt: [0.14898102 0.39847885 0.18889792]
Summary
  product   season  discount_percentage  sales_uplift_norm
0       A   summer             0.194152           0.175973
1       B   summer             0.112337           0.229735
2       C   summer             0.365488           0.374510
3       A   winter             0.186706          -0.028205
4       B   winter             0.378295           0.266675
5       C   winter             0.218578           0.146012
6       A  monsoon             0.148981           0.199073
7       B  monsoon             0.398479           0.307632
8       C  monsoon             0.188898           0.210134
```

Comment: Hello ! Actually if the constraint is set correctly, the solution should lie on it : f(x) = 20 should be respected in the end. Indeed increasing the cost should tend to yield better sales results overall (higher discounts).